# Select changes div state with or statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<option value="55">Clothing - Mens</option>
<option value="56">Clothing - Womens</option>
<option value="67">Film Music & Books</option>
<option value="69">Food & Drink</option>
```

I want to show a div when either "Clothing - Mens" or "Clothing - Womens" is chosen, so I'm using, which works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#category').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);

                if (($(this).val() == '55') || ($(this).val() == '56')) {
                    $('#fashion').show();
                    } else { $('#fashion').hide(); }

            } else { 
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true); 
            }
        });

});
```

But is there a way to shorten that? I've tried both of the following but neither work

```
if ($(this).val() == ('55','56')) { 

if ($(this).val() == ('55' || '56')) {
```

In both above cases, option value 56 works but 55 does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery's `inArray`..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
if ($.inArray($(this).val(),["55","56"]) != -1) {
```

Working example.. http://jsfiddle.net/FYNKc/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not working for me. have updated question with full js code that I'm using to see if anything is throwing it out

Comment: I've updated the answer..the problem is that we were comparing number 56 with string "56"..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly us `this.value` instead of `$(this).val();`

```
if ($.inArray(this.value, ['55','56']) != -1) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not working for me. have updated querstion with full js code that I'm using to see if anything is throwing it out